# Some .rpt files not removing from Temp folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am creating report files and exporting these as pdf. And I am disposing streams and report documents at the end. But, always some .rpt files are staying in Temp folder and I can't delete them. After recycling application pool all files are removed by IIS.
Then, after 1 or 2 hours new .rpt files are creating in Temp folder. And after somewhile, application throws `Server has not enough memory for operarition`. And, IMHO the reason is temp files. Here is the code I am using to export report as pdf.

```
    ReportDocument report = DownloadPDF.GetReport(id);

    MemoryStream stream = (MemoryStream)report.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + id+ ".pdf");

    report.Close();
    report.Dispose();
    try
    {
        Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
    }
```